# Bounding algebraic numbers away from the Gaussian integers

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis

Let $\alpha$ be an algebraic number with degree $\leq d$ and (absolute multiplicative) height $\leq H$. Then we can say a couple of things about such $\alpha$:

(1) We know the set of all $\alpha$ satisfying the above restriction is finite (Northcott).

(2) One can (via well known relations between height and Mahler measure) show that the following (rather crude) bound holds: $\frac{1}{(4H)^d} \leq |\alpha| \leq (2H)^d$.

(3) If $\alpha$ is NOT a Gaussian integer, then there exists $r_{H,d}>0$ such that $dist (\alpha , \mathbb{Z}^2) \geq r_{H,d}$, where $dist(\alpha , \mathbb{Z}^2)$ is the distance of $\alpha$ to the nearest integer lattice point.

Is it possible to find the explicit formula $r_{H,d}$?

Many thanks!

Comment: Let $\beta$ be a Gaussian integer. You want to bound $ |\alpha-\beta|$. So you need to bound degree and height of $\alpha-\beta$. The degree is clearly bounded by $2d$, and the height by something like $(2H+1)^2$.